# Where is hosts.txt that parallel-ssh uses

Tags: linux, ssh

this might sound silly but I'm really stuck here...

I want parallel-ssh to preform operations on multiple hosts and I know I have to put their IPs in file hosts.txt, but where is this fabled hosts.txt file? Or if I have to create it, where? Because I keep getting this:

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'hosts.txt'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create it.  one host per line.

create a file called **hosts.txt** and in the contents have:

```
host1.mydomain.com  
host2.mydomain.com
```

then you pass that file in as an option `pssh -h hosts.txt ...`

That file can have any name really, so long as it's a list of hostnames.  You could save it as **myhosts.txt**, as an example.

```
pssh -h myhosts.txt ...
```

You can create this file where ever you like.  If you are on a windows machine you can create it in c:\temp or on a *nix box in /tmp/ or where ever.

then you can go:

`pssh -h c:\temp\hosts.txt`  or... 
`pssh -h /tmp/hosts.txt`  or...
`pssh -h c:\temp\myhosts.txt`

Comment: made an edit.  You can place the file anywhere you can get to.

Comment: ok you answered my question there, but now I keep getting this:
[1] 10:03:51 [FAILURE] 10.0.0.1 Exited with error code 255

Comment: For future readers: If you get this error 100% of the time, be sure to check any aliases you might have defined! On linux this is done easily by `which pssh` - you may have aliased to something like `pssh='pssh -h my_hosts_file_which_is_gone_now.txt'`

Answer (score 1):

You can specify it with the `-h` option or with the `PSSH_HOSTS` environment variable:

```
 pssh [OPTIONS] -h hosts.txt prog [arg0] ...
```